# Arrays of NSObjects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsobject

I've created an object, and now I'm trying to create an array full of these objects. I've tried a few different things with no success.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you mean you created a *class* and want to create an array of instances of that class.

Comment: As a general rule, please let us know *what* few different things you tried with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it one of two ways, with `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`.

```
id obj1, obj2, obj3;

// This creates a static array
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];

// This creates a dynamic array
NSMutableArray *mutarray = [NSMutableArray array];
[mutarray addObject:obj1];
[mutarray addObject:obj2];
[mutarray addObject:obj3];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray * arrayOfFoos = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  Foo * f = [[Foo alloc] init];
  [arrayOfFoos addObject:f];
  [f release];
}
```

Comment: can I then just access the objects as one would expect? arrayOfFoos[i]?

Comment: @submergd you'd really need to have a look at the doc

Comment: @submergd you could if `NSArray` were a C-style array, except that it's not.  Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `NSArray`, take a look at Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

If you wanna add them incrementally consider using a mutable collection like an `NSMutableArray` (here in the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html))